# Scale bitmap to specific size, keeping aspect ratio and filling the rest with 0 alpha pixels

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-glide

I've been searching for a solution to this problem for quite some time and haven't found anything to match my needs yet.

I want to scale a bitmap to a specific size while maintaining aspect ratio.
Think of it as scaling a bitmap using fitCenter in an ImageView, only in a new bitmap.

The source bitmap has to fit inside the destination bitmap which has a specific size, and the rest of the pixels have to be transparent.

I have tried using Glide like so:

```
Glide.with(context).load(url)
                            .asBitmap()
                            .override(1280, 720)
                            .fitCenter()
                            .into(1280, 720)
                            .get();
```

But this method returns a bitmap that fits only width (or hight) and wraps the size.

I've heard that using Canvas is a possible solution but haven't found any way of achieving my goal using it.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. I will post any needed clarifications if requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it using this function:

```
Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap image, int destWidth, int destHeight) {
    Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap(destWidth, destHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    float originalWidth = image.getWidth();
    float originalHeight = image.getHeight();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);

    float scaleX = (float) 1280 / originalWidth;
    float scaleY = (float) 720 / originalHeight;

    float xTranslation = 0.0f;
    float yTranslation = 0.0f;
    float scale = 1;

    if (scaleX < scaleY) { // Scale on X, translate on Y
        scale = scaleX;
        yTranslation = (destHeight - originalHeight * scale) / 2.0f;
    } else { // Scale on Y, translate on X
        scale = scaleY;
        xTranslation = (destWidth - originalWidth * scale) / 2.0f;
    }

    Matrix transformation = new Matrix();
    transformation.postTranslate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
    transformation.preScale(scale, scale);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, transformation, paint);
    return background;
}
```